# Overriding Enabled property in a custom CheckBox

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, controls

I have a custom CheckBox class. I have overrided getters for Enabled and Visible property (I need some complicated behavior).

When I the run application and debug it I found that my Enabled's getter is not called at all. At the same time the `Visible` property is called correctly, and I get the desired result.

```
public class CustomCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    public override bool Visible
    {
        get
        {
            bool result;

            //Do something

            return result;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Visible = value;
        }
    }
    public override bool  Enabled
    {
        get
        {
            bool result;

            //Do something

            return result;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Enabled = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I have some suspicions about it. Maybe during the render stage CheckBox does not call the Enabled property, but looks for the needed attribute within InputAttribute collection. I'm not sure and do not know how to determine it.

Comment: because there is no answer was recieved I provide my own solution. It's not perfect but seems that it works. I override Render method in that way:  <br/> if (!Enabled)
    this.InputAttributes.Add("DISABLED", "DISABLED");
   else
    this.InputAttributes.Remove("DISABLED");
   base.Render(writer);